# Honor 9 fails to update apps over Wi-Fi

Tags: google-play-store, huawei, emui

There is a new Huawei Honor 9 with Google services pre-installed.

When I download/update an app via wi-fi it gets "Downloading..." for a long time and then it finishes as:

> Can't be downloaded. Try again, and if the problem continues, get help troubleshooting. Error 503

Other phones/notebooks consumes the same wi-fi internet without a problem. Honor's Chrome can access internet normally. Google Play app can access wi-fi internet too (loading app info and pictures) except the one thing - downloading/installing an app. There is no such error via *mobile data*.

To make the things yet more complicated I am able to install certain apps but the majority still fails.

I cleared Google Play cache. Also the wi-fi permission is given to every app listed.

Model STF-L09 / Build STF-L09C10B170 / EMUI 5.1 / Android 7.0

Comment: There is no "Downloads" or "Download manager" listed among  apps.

Comment: 10x, I found it and cleared its data. Didn't help.

Comment: Resetting my router to the factory state solved that misteryous problem.

Comment: That's good. Please post the answer yourself. It would help others and delete earlier comments to keep it clean :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resetting my router to the factory state solved that mysterious problem.